# IntelliJ IDEA "Cannot resolve symbol" errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I've tried all the usual methods of solving these errors such as checking the JDK used, to add a JPA facet with Hibernate as the default JPA provider, invalidate the caches, etc,. But none of them seem to be clearing the errors.

The dependencies I'm using are: **Spring Web, Lombok, Spring Data JPA and MySQL Driver.**

[image: Image showing all the errors]
[image: pom.xml file]

Comment: Does the code compile when you run `mvn package`? If so: open the "maven"-tab on the right, click the "reload" icon within the maven tab on the upper left (should read "Reload All Maven Projects" as hover text). This will re-trigger a complete rescan and download missing dependencies.

Comment: Show your pom.xml if the compilation fails in the command line Maven too.

Comment: @Turing85 How do I run the mvn package alone? Nonetheless, I tried reloading it the way you said but it sadly didn't change anything.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've edited in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Open a terminal, navigate to the project root, run `mvn clean package`.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please try replacing `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistence`.

Comment: @Turing85 Replacing javax.persistence with jakarta.persistence worked !  Any insights on why this was the case? I tried looking it up but couldn't find any. Thank you for the help and I read the article you mentioned above too.

Comment: ["*... the Eclipse Foundation and Oracle have been unable to agree on terms of an agreement for the Eclipse Foundation community to modify the javax package namespace or to use the Java trademarks currently used in Java EE specifications.   Instead, Eclipse and Oracle have agreed that the javax package namespace cannot be evolved by the Jakarta EE community. As well, Java trademarks such as the existing specification names cannot be used by Jakarta EE specifications.*"](https://eclipse-foundation.blog/2019/05/03/jakarta-ee-java-trademarks/)